# Continuously interpolate over transformed discrete signal

Tags: continuity, transformation, interpolation

Imagine that I have an $\mathbb{K}^{n \times m}$ Matrix called $ A $ *(It can also be an 2-dimensional image with the width of `m` and the height of `n`, with $\mathbb{K}$ being a colour-vector)*.

I also have a non-linear, non-affine transformation $T : \mathbb{N_0}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2 $, which one could interpret as an index-transformation function.
In this sense I mean the following:

If the function $T$ was defined as $T(i,j)=(i+2,\frac{j}{2})$, an 'application' of $T$ onto the matrix' indices would result in following matrix transformation:

```
A := | 3 1 |
     | 4 2 |

     | - - - |
A' = | 3 - 1 |
     | 4 - 2 |
```

The result is technically not a matrix, as its indices are not from the field $\mathbb{N_0}$, but from the field $\mathbb{R}$.
As you can see the result 'matrix' has some undefined entries (marked with an `-`).

My question is now: how can I continuously interpolate over the matrix (e.g. Bezier or Bicubic interpolation) in order to fill the 'matrix' empty entries?

---

*It may be easier to see the result as image with floating-point pixel indices, which I now have to fill with 'colour'.*

In order to maybe better visualise the problem, I've drawn a small sketch:
[image]

Comment: Stochastic matrix maybe.

Comment: @mathreadler: May I ask how exactly a stochastic matrix may solve the problem? As far as I was aware a stochastic matrix is a regular matrix with all values being in the range of `[0..1]` and the sum of it being `1`. Obviously I am mistaken. Could you maybe give me further indications? Is it a matrix with an 'infinite' amount of indices (e.g. between two other indices)?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** You can try for example the matrix

$$\bf S = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0.5&0.5\\0&1\end{array}\right]$$

now on any $2\times 2$ matrix $\bf M$ calculate ${\bf SMS}^T$ and see what happens.

Comment: Well, I thought of that -- the problem however is, that my resulting 'matrix' is ...well .... not really a matrix, as it has indices in the space of $\mathbb{R}$ and not $\mathbb{N}$, which means that regular matrix multiplication will not work.

Comment: Of course it will work. You just need to start keeping track of the indices by storing them separately in a list or array or something.

Comment: oh I see. I will try to implement it and I will notify you of my progress later. Thank you very much in advance for your help, Sir.

Comment: Yes try and build and do stuff and you will find your way forward. You don't need to sir me, I am merely a house cat in this big wondrous world of mathematics.